# File Handling, Dictionary and Maps

Tags: python

So I was supposed to find the number of occurences of a text file, by following this kind of format. [image][image]

But my code probably is entirely wrong.

```
text = open('text3.txt','r')
d = dict()
fname = input('Enter the file name:')
l = input('Enter letter to be searched:')
k = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            for letter in i:
                if(letter == 1):
                    k = k+1
print('Occurences of the letter:')
print(k)
```

Can someone help me for this?

Comment: Hi Drey. Please be more precise about what is wrong with the output. Don't keep the community guessing. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah you can iterate the characters instead:

```
fname = input('Enter the file name:')
char = input('Enter letter to be searched:')
i = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  data = f.read()
  for each in data:
    if each == char:
      i += 1
print(i)
```

Comment: when I tried to copy your entire code, the problem in line 4 is says thatFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text3.txt'

Comment: in your code, you depend on user input for the filename. If you want to hardcode the filename then replace fname with "text3.txt" and make sure it is in the same directory as the python script.

Comment: okay, so I tried adding a new file in idle and saved it as text3.txt and used the same code and it worked.